# Is the plural of CV: CV or CVs when the pluralised noun does not end in -s?

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, irregular

[The answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56010/3515) to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not) outlines a general rule for pluralising acronyms:

> The general rule is that you should **not** use an apostrophe to form the plurals of nouns, abbreviations, or dates made up of numbers: just add -s (or -es, if the noun in question forms its plural with - es).

However, it is not clear from that answer what should be done if the noun in question uses does **not** end in either *-s* or *-es*.

What is the correct plural abbreviation for Curriculum Vitae?

I think the plural is Curriculum Vitarum (or possibly Curricula Vitae), which would make the plural abbreviation CV too. Use of the *-s* suffix suggests Curriculum Vitaes (or possibly Curriculums Vitae) which seems wrong.

What is correct?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth those appear to be works where adding the "s" makes the abbreviated word a plural, that general case doesn't answer this one.

Comment: How does Hugo's answer not answer this?

Comment: @tchrist Not really, no. That really accurately clarifies the distinction between CDs and CD's, but doesn't answer this one (though it does rule out CV's, which is helpful). If you can explain why that is a complete answer to this question I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I believe the correct pluralization for curriculum vitae should be curricula vitae, not curriculum vitarum, as curriculum is the noun. Which would still lead one to use CV for the plural.

Comment: It reads: “The general rule is that you should not use an apostrophe to form the plurals of nouns, abbreviations, or dates made up of numbers: just add -s (or -es, if the noun in question forms its plural with - es). For example:

...
MP MPs (e.g. Local MPs are divided on this issue.)”

Comment: @tchrist only the noun in question is Latin, not English, and doesn't use either -s or -es in its plural.

Comment: @tchrist I've updated the question to make it clear what I'm asking about and why [Hugo's general answer for acronyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56010/3515) does not appear to cover this case.

Comment: @Cameron I've updated the question, cheers.

Comment: If you are alleging that CV is **not** pronounced SEE-VEE or that CVs is **not** pronounced SEE-VEEs, then you'd best make that clear, with supporting evidence to that effect. Otherwise this makes no sense.

Comment: @tchrist Huh? I'm not alleging anything about how the letters of the acronym is pronounced. Are _you_ saying that the rule for written English acronyms should depend on the pronunciation of the letters and not the words? If so then that would be new information not present in the answer you insist this is a duplicate of. Also, would Loot Boxes be LBes (based on _boxes_) or LBs (based on _ell-bees_), because my understanding of Hugo's answer would be the former, which in turn suggests that it's the plural of the noun, not the letter, that matters.

Comment: Oh, I was about to say the same thing. How do you pronounce the abbreviation CV, do you pronounce it in the English or in the Latin way? Do you always say the full form? Do you use the Latin plural form? When pluralising letters we add the -s, "How many As did you get in your semester?" This is a question about common sense, it's got nothing to do with English *per se* (Ha! Note Bene  the Latin expression)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd pronounce it _see-vee_, but it's not clear from the question this is a duplicate of that pronunciation of the letters is the rule. An A grade is not an abbreviation, the top grade is just called "A"; I don't think it's the same thing (also, based on [Hugo's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56010/3515), wouldn't it be _"How many A's did you get in your semester?"_)

Comment: The plural of an abbreviation, at least in colloquial speech, doesn't have much to do the full phrase in the UK. The abbreviation MP is pluralised as MPs regardless of whether it stands for Military Policemen or Members of Parliament. In the first case neither word ends in an 's' and in the second the plural ending in an 's' is the first word, however no one would refer to Members of Parliament as MsP (pronounced EMMS PEE as EMM ESS PEE is something different).

Comment: @BoldBen cheers, that's pretty much what I'm getting at - I thought that Military Police would be MP, Very Important People would be VIP and so on (in terms of correct English - clearly pluralised acronyms such as MPs are commonly understood) - so "The MP need to get all the VIP out of here" would be correct, but "The MPs need to get all the VIPs out of here" would be commonly understood. That isn't made clear in the question this is flagged as a duplicate of; add that clarity to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Keith If we are going to refer to people and things by initials then we need some way to indicate plurals. If we are to insist that the initials must stand strictly for the words they represent and not take an 's' when they are plural then indicating plurals becomes very difficult. I could just about accept MsP for Members of Parliament but what you would do for Military Policemen I'm not so sure. You can't even use MPn because the singular and plural both end in the same letter. Apologies to any lady members of the Military Police of course, I'm just trying to make a linguistic point.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia uses "CVs", so I'd go with that

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae

Comment: Cheers, but that's just an example of usage. I'm sure that CVs is commonly understood, but is it correct?