# How can I make initialisms that refer to plurals possessive?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, initialisms

I want to know if it is correct to treat AF as a proper name and thus write "AF's concept" or if I must take the words of the initialism into consideration and write "AFs' (as I would write "Armed Forces' concept of protection" if I didn't use the initialism).

The link provided gave me conflicting answers about which way is right, and the main issue in the argumentation seemed to me to be the dubble s-es.

Comment: AFAIK there shouldn't be an apostrophe. And "s" shoukd be omitted as well if the acronym stands for something that is already plural

Comment: Maybe worth looking at this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not

Comment: Jodes -. you mean I should write "AF concept of defence"?

Comment: Sorry my mistake - I missed you want possessive.  I'd make it possessive like a normal word. "AF's concept of defence" .  But it does feel a bit weird.