# the plural of a 'word-as-a-word'

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

1-the words tumbled out **so** fast that I could barely hear them’

2-don't look **so** worried’

3-I'm not **so** foolish as to say that

**How would you refer to the sub-modifiers/adverbs (so) in sentence 1,2,3.**

a) so in sentences 1,2 and 3

b) so's in sentences 1,2 and 3

c) the so's in sentence 1,2 and 3

d) the so in sentence 1,2 and 3

e)...... type your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use either "sos" or "so's" - there's a broader discussion of when it's appropriate to use an apostrophe to pluralise [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not).

But I'd say the best way would be so avoid pluralising the word "so" altogether.

> the instances of "so" in sentences 1, 2 and 3