# Plurals of acronyms on BBC website

Tags: british-english, apostrophe, acronyms, greengrocers-apostrophe

> Sinn Féin has confirmed that one of their MLA's has removed a clamp from the front wheel of his car, using what appears to be bolt cutters, in Belfast.

This is from the BBC [website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-northern-ireland-42933506).

I know the merits of **'s** for plural acronyms is covered at [Plurals of acronyms, letters, numbers — use an apostrophe or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not)

but my question is simply: is this a BBC mistake or is it becoming  standard. I'd expected the BBC to be very precise on such matters.

---

**EDIT**:  It was corrected on BBC website the next day.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I tried to make this focussed on the BBC to avoid it being a duplicate, but if it is judged so, I won't complain too much!

Comment: You can download the BBC News style guide here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/journalism/news-style-guide/article/art20131010112740749 It says "Neither are apostrophes generally needed for plurals (eg: MPs, MBEs), but they are for the pluralisation of letters of the alphabet (eg: Our task now is to dot the i's and cross the t's)." Based on that, it seems to be a mistake. But I think this is not so much a question about the English language when answering it gets to the point of looking through the BBC style guide to see what style choices this particular organization has made.

Comment: @sumelic I just found this page http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/contact-us/editorial to report mistakes so I submitted a report with a link to this question. I'm interested to see how (or perhaps I should say if) they respond.

Comment: As @tchrist has said, 'Questions about [individual] style guides are off-topic here.' It is inappropriate to ask 'Is the BBC not following its own guidelines here?' on ELU. 'Is this construction used by the BBC acceptable?' is a different matter. And the plurals of acronyms etc have been addressed here before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an error, but not in my view very serious.

The [BBC style guide](https://academy.files.bbci.co.uk/assets/guides/news/bbc_news_style_guide_searchable_version.docx) says explicitly

> **MLA**
>
> (Member of the Legislative Assembly) is the abbreviation to use for a member of the Northern Ireland Assembly; plural: **MLAs**.

and takes a similar approach to other examples.

Comment: This depends on your style guide. I use CMOS. I use only 's' for the plural of acronyms ending in a capital or expressions ending in digits. For a single letter I use an apostrophe to mind my p's and q's.

Comment: But it's an in-house error not an English language error. They've not followed their own style guide. Nobody else needs to follow it.