# How to pluralize the following initialism

Tags: initialisms

I'm having difficulty finding an answer to this. If I need to pluralize the following phrase "Request for Support" to "Requests for Support" would I put it as, RFSs, RFS's, RsFS, R.F.S.'s, R.'sF.S. or RFSes? This is an honest argument I am having at work and need an answer ASAP. Thank you!

Comment: This question HAS NOT been asked before because no one has asked about an RFS before so none of those other questions helped me.

Answer (score 2):

**RFS** is an *initialism*. In other words, you sound out the individual letters that make up its short form.

(Unlike like **NAFTA** and **NATO** which are *acronyms*, and are pronounced as words.)

It used to be that the plural form of an initialism (or acronym) had an added **'s**. Currently, most style guides say to drop the apostrophe and simply add the **s**.

Regardless of the past use of **'s** or the current use of just **s**, this is done whether the initialism *already* stands for something plural or not. It's not what it stands for that is being "counted," it's the initialism itself.

Therefore, the plural of **RFS** is most commonly recognized today as **RFSs**.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/initialisms):

```
When you are forming the plural of an initialism, you do not need to use
an apostrophe, for example:

MPs
   e.g. MPs voted against the bill.
CDs
   e.g. I bought some new CDs today.

Note that the possessive form of initialisms is formed in the usual way,
with an apostrophe + s
```

[The Chicago Manual of Style Q&A](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Plurals/faq0013.html):

```
What is the correct way to make acronyms or initialisms plural? 

If you can stop thinking of the spelled-out meaning of the acronym and
just treat the acronym itself as a word with its own meaning, you should
be able to add that little s without fretting.
```

[Public Works and Government Services Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect1&info0=1.04#zz1):

```
Add an s, but not an apostrophe, to form the plural of most
abbreviations.
```

(Note that the page provided by the *Public Works and Government Services Canada* link discusses a number of specific exceptions—however, the answer I quoted here applies to **RFS**.)

Comment: Have you got a citation for this being considered correct in older English? I'm struggling to see why it would ever make sense to use an apostrophe in this way.

Comment: @Turkeyphant I don't have any *specific* citations for older guidance; I'm mainly repeating what other authorities have said used to be older guidance. For other references that say the same thing (but not necessarily with a specific citation either), see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Use_in_forming_some_plurals), [Word Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plural-of-cd.38733/post-12929607), [Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-make-rbi-plural), and even [this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56010/291924).