# Apostrophe to indicate the plural of a mathematical object

Tags: apostrophe, mathematics

I have a question on the use of apostrophe to indicate the plural of a mathematical object.

Consider the sentence: "*There are many values of X such that the statement is true*".

In math, often we re-write this sentence as "*There are many X's such that the statement is true*".

Now, my question is: which one is correct (or preferred) between

"*There are many X's such that the statement is true*"

and

"*There are many Xs such that the statement is true*"

In case they are both wrong, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

A single letter **X** in mathematical notation indicates an *unknown*. You would write the plurals as **Xs** or perhaps as **X**s (the former has both X and s in bold; the latter has only the X in bold.)

Note how **Xs** and **Ys** are used at our sister [mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Xs).

Comment: While sometimes adding `'s` can be acceptable for plurals of single letters (see, for instance answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/55970/102510)), particularly in mathematics, where it is common to use apostrophes/primes to denote other variables (e.g. **X**, **X'**, **X''** etc.), or for differentiation, it would be liable to cause confusion.

Comment: Good point! Mathematics has a complex orthography and uses some subtle typography to express this. That unknown x is different from X and has numerous variations (which I can't express well typographically with MathJax). Besides X, there's "X-prime," "X-double-prime," "X-bar,"  "X vector," "X-hat"  (you get the picture). I think Xs and xs could lead to excess.